# Seleccionar el id más alto de la tabla en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hago este `SELECT` con PHP, pero a la hora de imprimir la variable `$id` me imprime lo siguiente:

> ƒ Array() { [native code] }.

¿Alguna idea?

He puesto:

```
SELECT MAX(id_event) AS id
FROM evento
```

En PHPMyAdmin y me imprime el número correcto.

```
<?php
$queryADD = "SELECT MAX(id_event) AS id FROM evento";
$eventADD = $conn->prepare($queryADD);
$eventADD->execute();
$eventRes = $eventADD->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$id = null;

if (count($eventRes) > 0) {
    $id = $eventRes;
    $id++;
}
```

Comment: `$eventRes` es un array. `fetch` devuelve un array con los resultados aunque solo tengas un valor.

Comment: Es verdad, Gracias :')

Comment: Si tu idea es usar ese `id` para calcular el siguiente que debes usar en un registro que introducirás posteriormente, debes hacerlo todo en una transacción y haciendo uso de `FOR UPDATE` de la siguiente manera: `SELECT id_event id FROM evento ORDER BY id_event DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`. Si usas `MAX(id_event)` no se "congelará" el registro para evitar que otro proceso obtenga también ese mismo `id` y terminéis duplicando registro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$eventRes` es un array, por eso cuando lo muestras sale `array()`

Para mostrar el `id` tendrias que hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$eventRes['id']
```

Espero te pueda ayudar

Comment: Gracias. Eso es :)